# Windows Server 2003 scheduled tasks not running

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

The task which I want to run runs fine manually. But when I set a time for it to run using "Scheduled Tasks", it doesn't run.

What may be causing the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: does it display a gui interface?

Comment: it displays nothing

Comment: check the log file (from memory, in scheduled tasks go to the menu bar and choose 'Advanced', then 'View Log'. Do you get any clue as to why it does not run? Check the event log as well

Comment: @natxoasenjo, The log doesn't log anything for my scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the scheduled time/date that it runs, along with the user credentials it runs under.
Also make sure the current/date time is set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

On the Scheduled Task's property screen, do you have the 'Run only if logged on' checkbox checked?  Is the Enabled checkbox checked?

Comment: no i do not.....

Answer (score 1):

The scheduled task will not run if it **hasn't completed its previous run**.

So, ensure that your scheduled tasks are not running longer than the interval set.

To stop your current running task you can `Right Click` → `End Task`:

[image]

Also, use `schtasks /query /v /fo list` for a detailed view of the "state" of your scheduled tasks.